# Javascript function for counting numbers within strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, numbers

Newbie here. Trying to write a function that accepts an array of strings and counts the number of strings that can be converted to a number.
example: ['1', 'h','3','l','p','7'] should return 3.

```js
function countNumbers(arr) {
  for (let i of arr) {
    let num = parseInt(i);
    let total = 0
    if (num >= 0) {
      total++;
      return total
    }
  }
}

console.log(countNumbers(['1', 'h','3','l','p','7']));
```

Comment: To help you learn, instead of the complete solution, here's a hint: The [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function helps you determine if a value can be converted to a number.

Comment: Why your code returns 1: If you return from the for-loop, you stop the iteration, and your function returns immediately. As for your `parseInt` and `num >= 0` check, what about negative numbers?

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for your help! Originally I had it written as if(parseInt(i) !==NaN) but that wasn't working. I understand why now after reading about the isNaN function. As for the return inside the for loop, I've moved the return and the total variable outside the for loop.